# What is the difference between these two codes?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ExtJs, just stepped into some basic things and found that its very hard to get started as a beginner.

Below are the two ways of implementing Ext button:

**Sample1:**

```
var nextBtn = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Next >>',
    handler: function() {
        Ext.getDom('form_main').submit();
    },
    id: 'next',
    renderTo: 'next'
});
```

**Sample2:**

```
Ext.widget('button', {
text: 'some long title of my cool button',
scale: 'large',
cls: 'my-button',
width: 100,
renderTo: 'output'
});
```

My guess is beacuse of the version, it has changed. Please let me know what is the difference between these two codes.

Regards,

Comment: The only similarity is that they are both buttons.

Comment: I think the question is about the difference between using Ext.widget and new Ext.Button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to instantiate a class in ExtJS.

Take this definition as example:

```
Ext.define ('Ext.button.Button', {
  alias: 'widget.button' ,
  // here other properties and methods ...
});
```

Then you can chose one of these ways to instantiate Ext.button.Button:

First: javascript style

```
var button = new Ext.button.Button ({
  // props and methods
});
```

Second: ExtJS style with *Ext.create* method

```
var button = Ext.create ('Ext.button.Button', {
  // props and methods
});
```

Third: ExtJS style with *Ext.widget* method (it uses *alias* property)

```
var button = Ext.widget ('button', {
  // props and methods
});
```

I suggest you to use the second or the third way because they use ExtJS dynamic loader: **[here's the documentation](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system)**

Comment: great answer.  Was interested in the difference between the latter two - effectively the Ext.widget call lets you use the xtype short hand?

Comment: Thanks ;) Absolutely! Here's the doc: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-widget